# default java util binary-search returns wrong results

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I got very strange behavior from binary search in java util

this code

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
     int[] A={-1, 6, 3, 4, 7, 4} ;

     for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
     {
         System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(A,A[i])+"========="+A[i]);
     }
}
```

should display all values every element in the array with its index

but it works fine for all elements expect the second one

the returned values are

```
0=========-1
-5=========6
2=========3
3=========4
4=========7
3=========4
```

I tested it on java 7 and java 8 and it gave me the same results

you can test online on 
https://ideone.com/7wMFgG

Comment: Are you aware that [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works on sorted arrays only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the Javadoc of binarySearch you'll see that the array must be sorted :

```
/**
 * Searches the specified array of longs for the specified value using the
 * binary search algorithm.  The array must be sorted (as
 * by the {@link #sort(int[])} method) prior to making this call.  If it
 * is not sorted, the results are undefined.
...
```